# How to restrict in SSMS to allow remote connections only specific IP / Host

Tags: ssms

I cannot change sql server user. How can I restrict in SSMS to allow remote connections only specific IP / HostAddress.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7127602/6327676

Answer (score 3):

SSMS is only a tool that connects to a SQL Server instance. SQL Server listens on a specific IP address for connections. It doesn't really care which tool is connecting.

SQL Server is not like PostgreSQL that has a `pg_hba.conf` where you can restrict connections, nor is it MySQL where you assign permissions to a `user@source` combination when creating the user login.

### Answer

It's not currently possible by using simple means (PostgreSQL, MySQL), but if you are willing to start creating [Logon Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs), then you might be able to build a restriction that meets your requirements.

The SQL Syntax for triggers can be found in the article [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs). The article lists an example for a Logon Trigger.

Because your requirements are pretty dire, I am unable to provide a solid solution. Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/206142/edit) your question and provide as much details as possible.

```
USE master  
GO  
CREATE LOGIN login_test WITH PASSWORD = 'password' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON  
GO  
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO login_test
GO  
CREATE TRIGGER connection_limit_trigger  
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'login_test'  
FOR LOGON  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'login_test' AND  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions  
            WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND  
                original_login_name = 'login_test') > 3  
    ROLLBACK  
END
```

### Alternative

You could equally create a blocking firewall rule or hack the routing table on the server / network.